# Plone/Zope/ZODB: how to override storage method on a File field

Tags: python, plone, zope, zodb

I have a File Field in my Plone product that I want to allow the user to "Turn Off" blob storage.  The file will be stored elsewhere.  I can't seem to do it.

Below is my attempt.  I can't get `Products.Archetypes.Field.ObjectField.setStorage()` to recognize that this 'noStorage' instance "provides" `IStorage`.

Much inconsequential code has been removed for brevity, but the complete source can be found at https://github.com/flipmcf/rfa.kaltura

---

The Archetype schema includes "ATBlob.schema" to pull in the "File" field, then:

```
class KalturaVideo(ATBlob, KalturaBase.KalturaContentMixin):

    nostorage = NoStorage()
    directlyProvides(nostorage, INoStorage)

    def __init__(self, oid, **kwargs):
        if settings.storageMethod == u"No Local Storage":
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # 
            #(Pdb) IStorage.providedBy(self.nostorage)
            #True
            self.getField('file').setStorage(self, self.nostorage)
```

My Storage class and interface is really boring:

```
from zope.interface import implements
from ZODB.interfaces import IStorage
from zope.component.zcml import interface
from zope.interface import Interface

class INoStorage(IStorage):
    pass 

class NoStorage(object):
    """Completely skip storage on Plone."""
    implements(INoStorage)

    def __init__(self):
        pass 

    def close():
        pass

    def getName():
        return "NoStorage - Blackhole"

    #etc... lots of implemented methods that do nothing.
```

`configure.zcml` in the 'storage' package also:

```
<adapter
   factory=".storage.NoStorage"
   provides=".storage.INoStorage"
   for="Products.Archetypes.interfaces.field.IObjectField"
/>

<adapter
   factory=".storage.NoStorage"
   provides=".storage.IStorage"
   for="Products.Archetypes.interfaces.field.IObjectField"
/>
```

Now, within the `setStorage()` method of `Products.Archetypes.Field.ObjectField`:

```
def setStorage(self, instance, storage):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    #(Pdb) IStorage.providedBy(storage)
    #False
    #HeadDesk
    if not IStorage.providedBy(storage):
        raise ObjectFieldException, "Not a valid Storage method"
```

And when I debug, `IStorage.providedBy(storage)` returns `False`

Why would it return False in `setStorage` and `True` in the calling code?  Am I not registering the interface correctly?

Comment: What is the class for that `storage` instance?  Try going up the stack frame in the `pdb` shell and see what the variable that ultimately gets passed into `storage` actually is like in each of those frames.

Comment: Class looks good: (Pdb) self.nostorage
<rfa.kaltura.storage.storage.NoStorage object at 0x76598d0>
(Pdb) self.nostorage.__class__
<class 'rfa.kaltura.storage.storage.NoStorage'>

Comment: sorry about the confusing package & module name being the same (storage) - cleanup will happen.

Comment: https://github.com/flipmcf/rfa.kaltura/commit/317bf70f62569a1d88912f70d927b4d15d82a51e

Comment: It appears from the pasted code that checking `IStorage.providedBy(storage)` is returning False in both inside `setStorage` and in the calling context.  Is that a typo?

Comment: That is a typo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the module `Products.Archetypes.Field`, the `IStorage` instance there is actually sourced from this:

```
from Products.Archetypes.interfaces.storage import IStorage
```

Comparing the interface resolution order (via `__iro__`) we get

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(ZODB.interfaces.IStorage.__iro__)
(<InterfaceClass ZODB.interfaces.IStorage>,
 <InterfaceClass zope.interface.Interface>)
>>> pp(Products.Archetypes.interfaces.storage.IStorage.__iro__)
(<InterfaceClass Products.Archetypes.interfaces.storage.IStorage>,
 <InterfaceClass zope.interface.Interface>)
```

As the `INoStorage` was subclassed from `ZODB.interfaces.IStorage`, and that interface class isn't the parent of `Products.Archetypes.interfaces.storage.IStorage` which the `setStorage` calls `providedBy` on, the `NoStorage` class as define will not satisfy that check.  To solve this, just have `INoStorage` simply inherit from the Archetype version of the `IStorage` and implement all its methods and it should work as intend.

That said, you could simply your code somewhat further with regards to the way you provide the interfaces, see this example:

```
>>> class INoStorage(Products.Archetypes.interfaces.storage.IStorage):
...     pass
... 
>>> class NoStorage(object):
...     zope.interface.implements(INoStorage)
... 
>>> nostorage = NoStorage()
>>> Products.Archetypes.interfaces.storage.IStorage.providedBy(nostorage)
True
```

Inheritances of the `Interface` subclasses will persist correctly through without extra `directlyProvides` definitions, so you can just drop that extra call inside the `KalturaVideo` class definition.  Naturally, you can just do `from ... import IStorage` and simply that to `class INoStorage(IStorage)`.  The example was done so to make things more explicitly visible.

Comment: Thank you!   Yes, the extra 'directlyProvides' was just me banging on the code.  I felt I shouldn't need it.  Thanks for clarifying that too!